# JavaScript Form Values - Replace Value with Variable & Calculate Sum of Variables

Tags: javascript, variables, replace

I've been searching for a solution on this but haven't been able to find anything I can understand.

I'm working on the piece of code below - I have simplified the output for ease of reading.

```
function CreateMsg() { 
var MsgDOM = document.getElementById("MSG"); 

MsgDOM.innerHTML = '<p>calculation.value</p><li>How you view God or a Higher Power: ' + document.forms[0].godview.value + '<\/li><li>How you view your life in general: ' + document.forms[0].lifeview.value + '<\/li><li>How you approach life: ' + document.forms[0].level.value + '<\/li><li>What your inner voice and internal thoughts are busy with: ' + document.forms[0].emotion.value + '<\/li><li>How you are most likely to tackle challenges: ' + document.forms[0].process.value + '<\/li><li>The lessons (mirrors) you are currently working with: ' + document.forms[0].lessons.value + '<\/li>'; 
}
```

I have everything working fine so far, but I need to do a calculation that reads the 6 values that the output display is picking up.

The value has to be read, and then replaced from an array - the same array applies to all six variables.

So the output value for each of the elements in the output is one of a number of fixed text values, usually a number. So if the value is 1, for example, I want it to replace that value with a 2. If it's 2, then replace it with 4, etc. There's a string of about 20 values, but they are common to all six numbers I need to calculate.

Then I want it to take those six values and add them together, and print them to the output display where it says calculation.value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be reasonably easy to do, something like this should be what you're looking for!

```js
function CreateMsg() { 
    var MsgDOM = document.getElementById("MSG");

    let fieldsToRead = ["godview", "lifeview", "level", "emotion", "process", "lessons"];

    let inputArray = fieldsToRead.map((fieldName) => {
        return Number(document.forms[0][fieldName].value);
    });

    console.log(inputArray);

    // This determines how we map input fields to output fields.
    // We can add more elements as needed.
    let inputOutputMap = {
        0:0,1:2,2:4,3:6,4:8,5:10,6:12
    };

    // You can perform your calculations here!!
    let result = inputArray.reduce((total, input) => {
        total += (inputOutputMap[input] || 0);
        return total;
    }, 0); 

    MsgDOM.innerHTML = '<p>Calculation.value</p><li>How you view God or a Higher Power: ' + document.forms[0].godview.value + '<\/li><li>How you view your life in general: ' + document.forms[0].lifeview.value + '<\/li><li>How you approach life: ' + document.forms[0].level.value + '<\/li><li>What your inner voice and internal thoughts are busy with: ' + document.forms[0].emotion.value + '<\/li><li>How you are most likely to tackle challenges: ' + document.forms[0].process.value + '<\/li><li>The lessons (mirrors) you are currently working with: ' + document.forms[0].lessons.value + '<\/li><br><h3>Calculation total: ' + result + '</h3>'; 
}

CreateMsg();
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
          Godview:<br>
          <input type="text" name="godview" value="1"><br>
          Lifeview:<br>
          <input type="text" name="lifeview" value="2"><br>
          Level:<br>
          <input type="text" name="level" value="3"><br>
          Emotion:<br>
          <input type="text" name="emotion" value="4"><br>
          Process:<br>
          <input type="text" name="process" value="5"><br>
          Lessons:<br>
          <input type="text" name="lessons" value="6"><br>
        </form>
        <div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="MSG">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Terry! This did exactly what I was looking for! 

I have two small queries - neither is a train smash. 

First DW is giving me a syntax error on the let fieldsToRead line but the function is still executing? I am using CS6 in case my DW is outdated.

Then two of my variables are in text format: the one reads Dark Night of the Soul and the other reads 700 - 1000.

I can convert them to pure numbers, so it's not a train smash. Just wondering if and how I can change the expression to include text fields? 

Thank you SO much. Very greatly appreciated <3

Comment: I tried wrapping it in quotation marks, double and single and that just ignored that value.

Comment: You can switch on the field names in the reduce block and special case.some fields, that's probably the easiest approach!

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the comment?

Comment: Oh just in the block of code where we    do total += inputOutputMap, we could switch on the value of input.

Answer (score 0):

```js
hi
I go through code acording the requirement bellow is the solved code 

can sum the values from the array

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

    </head>

<body onload="">
    <form>

        <input type="text" id="godview" value="" />
        <input type="text" id="lifeview" value="" />
        <input type="text" id="level" value="" />
        <input type="text" id="emotion" value="" />
        <input type="text" id="process" value="" />
        <input type="text" id="lessons" value="" />

    </form>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnsend" value="save" onclick="return CreateMsg();" />
    </div>
    <div id="MSG">
       
    </div>
    <script>
        function CreateMsg() {
            var arr = [];
            var godv = document.forms[0].godview.value;
            var lifv = document.forms[0].lifeview.value;
            var levelv = document.forms[0].level.value;
            var emotionv = document.forms[0].emotion.value;
            var processv = document.forms[0].process.value;
            var lessonsv = document.forms[0].lessons.value;
            arr.push(godv);
            arr.push(lifv);
            arr.push(levelv);
            arr.push(emotionv);
            arr.push(processv);
            arr.push(lessonsv);
            alert(arr);
            var MsgDOM = document.getElementById("MSG");
           
            MsgDOM.innerHTML = '<p>calculation.value</p><li>How you view God or a Higher Power: ' + document.forms[0].godview.value + '<\/li><li>How you view your life in general: ' + document.forms[0].lifeview.value + '<\/li><li>How you approach life: ' + document.forms[0].level.value + '<\/li><li>What your inner voice and internal thoughts are busy with: ' + document.forms[0].emotion.value + '<\/li><li>How you are most likely to tackle challenges: ' + document.forms[0].process.value + '<\/li><li>The lessons (mirrors) you are currently working with: ' + document.forms[0].lessons.value + '<\/li>';
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```